# Adding Extra Fields to the WordPress User Profile

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a strange problem. I have added custom field to **User Profile** and used `the_author_meta()` function for display fields content. Yeasterday works everything great. But today it doesn't work.

Custom field is in User Profile.  When I click update profile - the content of fields remains in place (so information should be saved). But on authors page where I have `<?php the_author_meta( 'skills' ); ?>` happens nothing.

I followed this tutorial when I was creating my own custom field:
http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

And this one when I tried to find the error in my code:
http://bavotasan.com/2009/adding-extra-fields-to-the-wordpress-user-profile/

They both are similar. I worked with page templates since yesterday, so it maybe caused the problem. So I deleted everything what I've added since yesterday. But nothing changed.

Here is my code:

```
// CUSTOM FIELD IN USER ADMIN - SAVE
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );


function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

    <h3>Skills - Färdigheter</h3>

    <table class="form-table">

        <tr>
            <th><label for="skills">Skills</label></th>

            <td>
      <textarea type="text" name="skills" rows="4" cols="50" id="skills" class="regular-text"><?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'skills', $user->ID ) ); ?></textarea><br>      
                <span class="description">Please enter your skills.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<?php }  

// CUSTOM FIELD IN USER ADMIN
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        {return false;}

    /* Copy and paste this line for additional fields. Make sure to change 'twitter' to the field ID. */
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'skills', $_POST['skills'] );
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it works fine. Are you sure you're calling `<?php the_author_meta( 'skills' ); ?>` inside [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)?

Answer (score 0):

Now I think that you will save the user meta successfully. Only you need to display from them.

Now you can use the function "get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single);".
Visit it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for advice, but it doesn't work (maybe because I don't have loop.. I don't know). I used `echo $curauth->skills` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The solution was to use **`<?php echo $curauth->skills; ?>`**   instead of `<?php the_author_meta( 'skills' ); ?>` or `<?php get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single);  ?>`

I don't know why, but it doesn't matter :D